# How to hook up Microsoft Forms 2.0 event handlers using JScript

Tags: enterprise-architect, jscript

I'm trying to add a customized UI page to Sparx EA.  It provides adding ActiveX controls via scripting. Using JScript, I've done this, but since ActiveX has to be registered on each client, I'd rather use Microsoft Forms, already installed on all clients.

I've successfully built the UI, appearance wise, by adding a "Forms.Form.1" ActiveX object, and adding text boxes, labels & buttons to the controls property of the created form.
These objects support events, but I can't figure out how to assign an event handler.

Here is the JScript code I used to get the screen layout:

```
function _addControl(parentControl, controlProgId, controlName, left, top, width, height){
    var newControl = parentControl.controls.add(controlProgId, controlName,1);
    newControl.Name=controlName;
    newControl._SetLeft(left);
    newControl._SetTop(top);
    newControl._SetWidth(width);
    newControl._SetHeight(height);
    return newControl;
}

function main(){
    //Create main form
    var form = Repository.AddTab("ScriptedForm", "Forms.Form.1");
    if (null != form){
        //Add control
        var textBox1 = _addControl(form, "Forms.TextBox.1","TextBox1", 18,21,94,93);
        var textBox2 = _addControl(form, "Forms.TextBox.1","TextBox2", 120, 21, 91, 93);
        var btnTest = _addControl(form, "Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnTest", 60, 140, 90, 30);
        btnTest.Caption = "Test";

        //Here's where I assign the click event, but it's unhappy.
        btnTest.add_Click(this.TextBox1_Click);
    }
}
function TextBox1_Click(Object){
    Session.Prompt("Click", promptOK);
}
```

The add_Click event expects a parameter of type CommandButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler.
There's nothing I can create that could be submitted as the parameter.  I tried creating a JScript class duplicating the interface, but no joy.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running into several problems here at once.

## (1) Process Lifetime

As far as I understand your question and its context, you are somehow manually executing a `JScript` script. Doing this EA will internally start `SScripter.exe`. You see this in the *Debug* window:

[image: Debug window showing a new debug instance backed by SScripter.exe]

The process is effectively terminated after the script finishes (and thus also terminating any event handlers you might have registered in your `UserControl` or `Form` object).

## (2) Passing a `JScript` object instance as a .NET `delegate`

If you could somehow extend the lifetime of the script environment, and if you could pass something to your event you will realise that any object in your `JScript` code will be passed as a `System.__ComObject` to the .NET runtime inside EA. Therefore you cannot just register an event handler.
However when you evaluate the object from .NET you will find out it is not an `IDispatch` interface:

```
MemberNames: 
ToString, 
GetLifetimeService, 
InitializeLifetimeService, 
CreateObjRef, 
Equals, 
GetHashCode, 
GetType

TargetInvocationException@mscorlib: 'COM target does not implement IDispatch.'
```

I did a small test with the code below:

```
function MyClass(name)
{
  this.name = name;
}

MyClass.prototype.Invoke = function(value) 
{
  Session.Output("name " + value);
    return true;
}

function main()
{

  var myClass = new MyClass("Hotzenplotz");
  myClass.Invoke("some Value");

  var ctrl = new ActiveXObject("IMASE.TestUserControl2");
  ctrl.Repository = Repository;
  ctrl.JavaScriptObject = myClass;
}
```

```cs
[ProgId(Global.ADDIN_NAME + Global.DOT + "TestUserControl2")]
[Guid("87156dd9-e947-44bf-92a9-e9554a5b1844")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class TestUserControl2 : ActivexControl
{
  public static string TabName { get; } = Global.ADDIN_NAME;

  private static readonly Lazy<string> _controlId = new Lazy<string>(() =>
  {
    var attribute = typeof(TestUserControl).GetCustomAttribute<ProgIdAttribute>();
    return attribute.Value;
  });

  private Timer timer;

  public static string ControlId = _controlId.Value;

  public Repository Repository { get; set; }
  public object JavaScriptObject { get; set; }

  public TestUserControl2()
  {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += TimerEvent;
    timer.Interval = 5000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();
  }

  ~TestUserControl2()
  {
    Logger.Default.TraceInformation("I'm gonna die ... " + this.GetHashCode());
  }

  private void OnDispose(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    timer.Dispose();
  }

  private void TimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    Logger.Default.TraceInformation("I'm still alive ... " + this.GetHashCode());

    if(null == JavaScriptObject) return;

    try
    {
      var memberNames = JavaScriptObject.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy|BindingFlags.Public).Select(p => p.Name);
      Logger.Default.TraceInformation("memberNames: " + string.Join(", ", memberNames));

      var result = JavaScriptObject.GetType().InvokeMember("Invoke", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, JavaScriptObject, new object[] {"arbitraryString"});
      Logger.Default.TraceInformation("result: " + result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Logger.Default.TraceException(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

## (3) Another approach

Create a `UserControl` inside your addin (using `WinForm` or `Forms`) and use `ClearScript` as a ScriptEngine.

Pass `Session` and `Repository` from a EA script to your control (or do it otherwise such as a menu to  wprk around the lifetime problem) and have either your forms code load a script from the repository (or any other source). Then react on your event handlers to execute your `JScript` code as needed. I create a simple example that shows how to call a control from an EA `JScript` and call another `JScript` from inside your forms code that in turn will log to the Debug session or regular scripting output window:

```
function main()
{
  var ctrl = new ActiveXObject("IMASE.TestUserControl2");
  ctrl.Repository = Repository;
  ctrl.Session = Session;

  Session.Prompt("wait", promptOK);
}

main();
```

Inside your form code you invoke your `JScript` with `Repository` and other objects like this:

```cs
public Repository Repository { get; set; }
public object Session { get; set; }

using (var engine = new JScriptEngine())
{
  engine.AddHostObject("Repository", this.Repository);
  engine.AddHostObject("Session", this.Session);
  engine.Execute("Session.Output('Repository.ConnectionString: ' + Repository.ConnectionString);");
}
```

Here is an output of the above scripting interactions:

[image: Debug Window with messages from ClearSCript Engine inside ActiveX Control]

Side note: I personally do not see the need for using forms as we can dynamically register ActiveX controls at AddIn startup. For code on doing this you can have a look at the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/dfch/6a27bb1b9320c93456cee6d5b2b9d551

In addition, if you are using [`ClearScript`](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript) as the script host, you can directly connect to your (UI) events from your script code as described in question #16 of the [ClearScript FAQtorial](https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Tutorial/FAQtorial.html).